# Fetching values from drop down and filling it to another drop down and also for input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to create an object array that maps the first drop down key with second drop down value... Need to fetch object array from phpSimilarly on selecting tier drop down, fee drop down should gets updated as well as fee value should be in the input box.

Example : if i select Tier 1 in first drop down , then it should  change "tier 1- 100 rupees" in second drop down and also the input field should have updated value 100..

```
define('TIER_LIST', json_encode(
     array(
        '1' => 'Tier 1',
        '2' => 'Tier 2',
        '3' => 'Tier 3',
     )
 ));

  define('FEE_LIST', json_encode(
  array(
    '1' => 'Tier 1 -100 Rupees ',
    '2' => 'Tier 2 -200 Rupees',
    '3' => 'Tier 3 -300 Rupees',
  )
  ));

$tierList = json_decode(TIER_LIST,true);
$feeList = json_decode(FEE_LIST,true);

  // drop down fields
<select class='browser-default selectField' id="TierSelection">
                        <option value="">Choose your option</option>
                        <?php foreach($tierList as $value => $text) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>

<select class='browser-default selectField' id="FeeSelection">
                        <option value="">Choose your option</option>
                   <?php foreach($tierList as $value => $text) { ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>

  <input type = "text" id = "feeValue">

 var objArray = {tierdropdownkey : feedropdownValue } --->doubt in this creation # should not hard code

    $("#tierDropDownId").change(function()
   {
     var ddText = $(this).val();
   $.each(objArray,function(key,value)
   {
    if(ddText == key)
        $("#feeDropDownId").val(value);
    });
    });
```

Comment: this can be implemented with javascript .But I need to few things. You 1st option is to be selected by the user and then 2nd option to be filled automatically right. Is that you expecting. I can see that both options are filled with fetching data from a db.To provide a better answer please show shome values of the options.

Comment: it is defined from constant .. no DB here .. by selecting tier 1 from first drop down ,"Tier 1 -100 Rupees" has to be selected automatically in second drop down and the value of "100" has to be automatically filled in input field ...

Comment: i need mainly the objArray  : var objArray = {tierdropdownkey : feedropdownValue }

Comment: is that possible

Comment: easy please do update your c code with drop down value list. So that I can provide you a clean code

Comment: what has to be updated ??   <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>">  in this $value will be fetching the values from defined "tier list  and fee list for the respected drop downs."...  i need to use php to fetch  values from constant.. drop down values are defined above ..

Comment: oops sorry i didnt saw that

Comment: @if my answer fullfill your requirement please mark it as a answer.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your code with adding `jquery`. Also I have tested this code.Its working well.
[image: option 01]
[image: option 02]
[image: option 03]

How ever you need to modify this more What **happen if someone try to select the option 02 at the fist place**. So **for a validation please do modify the java script**.

```
<html>
<head>
<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>  
<body><?php
define('TIER_LIST', json_encode(
     array(
        '1' => 'Tier 1',
        '2' => 'Tier 2',
        '3' => 'Tier 3',
     )
 ));

  define('FEE_LIST', json_encode(
  array(
    '1' => 'Tier 1 -100 Rupees ',
    '2' => 'Tier 2 -200 Rupees',
    '3' => 'Tier 3 -300 Rupees',
  )
  ));

$tierList = json_decode(TIER_LIST,true);
$feeList = json_decode(FEE_LIST,true);
?>
  // drop down fields
<select class='browser-default selectField' id="TierSelection" onchange="onchangeFeeSelection()">
                        <option value="0">Choose your option</option>
                        <?php foreach($tierList as $value => $text) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>

<select class='browser-default selectField' id="FeeSelection">
                        <option value="">Choose your Fee option</option>
                   <?php foreach($feeList as $value => $text) { ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>

  <input type = "text" id = "feeValue">
<script>


                                            function onchangeFeeSelection(){
                                               var TierSelection = $("#TierSelection").val();

                                                if( TierSelection == 1){
                                                    $('select option:contains("Tier 1 -100 Rupees")').prop('selected',true);
                                                    $('#feeValue').val('100');
                                                }
                                                if( TierSelection == 2){
                                                    $('select option:contains("Tier 2 -200 Rupees")').prop('selected',true);
                                                    $('#feeValue').val('200');
                                                }
                                                if( TierSelection == 3){
                                                    $('select option:contains("Tier 3 -300 Rupees")').prop('selected',true);
                                                    $('#feeValue').val('300');
                                                }
                                                if( TierSelection == "0"){
                                                    $('select option:contains("Choose your Fee option")').prop('selected',true);
                                                    $('#feeValue').val('')
                                                } 

                                            }


                                            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it possible to do without hard coding this ?? select option:contains("Tier 1 -100 Rupees")' ...   and this  $('#feeValue').val('100');   values  will change in future too ..how to handle this

Comment: @balaji then you have to focus on to ajax. If it can be changed it means there should be a way to insert those data from the backend .So its better to use ajax

Comment: var objArray = {tierdropdownkey : feedropdownValue } --->doubt in this creation # should not hard code        can we  fetch key and values from php here ???  from my code .. if that is filled then i will get my desired output without hardcoding ...   if i hardcode like below i get my output .. please help for this...                                                                                                                           var objArray = {'1' => 'Tier 1 -100 Rupees ',  
        '2' => 'Tier 2 -200 Rupees',
        '3' => 'Tier 3 -300 Rupees'}